# Need a code to make tree structure from version names

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I have an array of versions  such as `["1.0.0.0","1.5.0.0","1.5.0.1","1.5.0.2","1.5.0.3","1.5.0.4","1.5.0.7","1.6.0.0","1.6.0.1","1.13.0.0","1.13.1.0","1.13.1.1","1.13.1.2","1.13.1.3","1.13.1.4","1.22.0.0","1.22.1.0","1.22.1.1"]`

I need to map it into tree like

`1.0.0.0
    |1.5.0.0
    ||1.5.0.1
    ||1.5.0.2
    ||1.5.0.3
    ||1.5.0.4
    ||1.5.0.7
    |1.6.0.0
    ||1.6.0.1
    |1.13.0.0
    ||1.13.1.0
    ||1.13.1.1
    ||1.13.1.2
    |1.22.0.0
    ||1.22.1.0
    ||1.22.1.1`

Can any one help with this using Java

Comment: I wonder why a simple sort won't work?

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375067/java-version-number-sort

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java version number sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375067/java-version-number-sort)

Comment: i doesn't really see a pattern in your sample output. But if you just want to sort it here is sample comparator for your case:
https://pastebin.com/8PKG3PU3

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve? This looks like you either want to print every version or to check versions.

For first case, iterate trough array and print it like:

`System.out.println("your item")`

In second case, you can simply check if your array contains version you are checking.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you would like to insert the input version into a Binary Search Tree (BST)
It will allow you to find requested versions in O(log(n)) time

These are the main steps to achieve your goal:
1) Use a java BST implementation.
2) Implement String Comparator, in order to determine which version is bigger.
3) Add elements to the tree.
4) Print elements in your favorite format.

1) I've used this implementation: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Trees/code/BST.java

2) I've implemented a comparator that maps version strings to integers.
It allows me to compare the encoded numeric values of the versions

public class VersionsComparator implements Comparator  {

```
@Override
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    String versionPattern = "(\\d+)[.](\\d+)[.](\\d+)[.](\\d+)";
    final int numOfMatchers = 2;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(versionPattern);
    Matcher[] matchers = new Matcher[numOfMatchers];
    matchers[0] = pattern.matcher(s1);
    matchers[1] = pattern.matcher(s2);

    for (Matcher matcher : matchers) {
        if(!matcher.matches()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid version format");
        }
    }

    int version1 = parseVersion(s1, matchers[0]);
    int version2 = parseVersion(s2, matchers[1]);

    return version2 - version1;
}

private  int parseVersion(String version, Matcher matcher) {
    int length = matcher.groupCount();
    int[] v = new int[length];
    int parsedVersion = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        v[i] = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(length - i));
        parsedVersion += Math.pow(10, i) * v[i];
    }

    return parsedVersion;
}
```

}

3) Adding all of the strings to the tree:

```
private static BST getBST(String[] strArr) {
    BST<String> bst = new BST<String>();
    Arrays.asList(strArr).stream().forEach(str -> bst.insert(str));
    return bst;
}
```

4) Printing the tree elements:

I've added my own printing style, by adding 2 methods to the BST class:

```
public void inOrderTraversalWithHierarchy() {
    inOrderWithHierarchyHelper(root, 0);
}

private void inOrderWithHierarchyHelper(Node r, int level) {
    if (r != null) {
        inOrderWithHierarchyHelper(r.left, level + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < level; System.out.print("|"), i++);
        System.out.println(r);
        inOrderWithHierarchyHelper(r.right, level + 1);
    }
}
```

This is the code of the client class:

public class CodeToMakeTreeStructureFromVersionNames {

```
public class VersionsComparator implements Comparator<String>{

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        String versionPattern = "(\\d+)[.](\\d+)[.](\\d+)[.](\\d+)";
        final int numOfMatchers = 2;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(versionPattern);
        Matcher[] matchers = new Matcher[numOfMatchers];
        matchers[0] = pattern.matcher(s1);
        matchers[1] = pattern.matcher(s2);

        for (Matcher matcher : matchers) {
            if(!matcher.matches()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid version format");
            }
        }

        int version1 = parseVersion(s1, matchers[0]);
        int version2 = parseVersion(s2, matchers[1]);

        return version2 - version1;
    }

    private  int parseVersion(String version, Matcher matcher) {
        int length = matcher.groupCount();
        int[] v = new int[length];
        int parsedVersion = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            v[i] = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(length - i));
            parsedVersion += Math.pow(10, i) * v[i];
        }

        return parsedVersion;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] versions = {"1.0.0.0","1.5.0.0","1.5.0.1","1.5.0.2","1.5.0.3","1.5.0.4","1.5.0.7","1.6.0.0","1.6.0.1","1.13.0.0","1.13.1.0","1.13.1.1","1.13.1.2","1.13.1.3","1.13.1.4","1.22.0.0","1.22.1.0","1.22.1.1"};
    printBST(getBST(versions));
}

private static BST<String> getBST(String[] strArr) {
    BST<String> bst = new BST<String>();
    Arrays.asList(strArr).stream().forEach(str -> bst.insert(str));
    return bst;
}

private static void printBST(BST bst) {
    bst.inOrderTraversalWithHierarchy();
}
```

}