# how to sort number include decimal using java?

Tags: java, sorting

There are numbers like this.
ex) 1 2 3 5.1 5.10 5.2 5.20 6

I want to sort them like this.
ex) 1 2 3 5.1 5.2 5.10 5.20

I tried using arranging using list and array and ArrayList, but it doesn't work.

How can I sort like upper side using java?

Comment: Could you post the code which you have tried so far?

Comment: Ok. First, post the code that you have tried. See [mcve] for how to do that. And secondly, going into the problem, what data type are you using for the numbers? You can only do this with String, or perhaps BigDecimal. Not with any of the primitive numbers like `float` or `double`, since there is no difference between 5.1 and 5.10 in a `float` or `double`.

Comment: please wait. i will add my code in this post!

Comment: Do you understand that your desired results make no sense mathematically?

Answer (score 1):

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    String[] arr = { "1", "2", "3", "5.1", "5.10", "5.2", "5.20", "6" };
    
    ToIntFunction<String> sortByIntegerPart = doubleNumber -> {
        int pos = doubleNumber.indexOf('.');
        String str = pos == -1 ? doubleNumber : doubleNumber.substring(0, pos);
        return Integer.parseInt(str);
    };
    ToIntFunction<String> sortByFractionalPart = doubleNumber -> {
        int pos = doubleNumber.indexOf('.');
        String str = pos == -1 ? "0" : doubleNumber.substring(pos + 1);
        return Integer.parseInt(str);
    };
    Comparator<String> sortByIntFractParts = Comparator.comparingInt(sortByIntegerPart)
                                                       .thenComparingInt(sortByFractionalPart);

    List<String> sorted = Arrays.stream(arr).sorted(sortByIntFractParts)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(sorted);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Erwin Bolwidt is right mathematically there is no difference between 5.1 and 5.10. Your sorting problem should be solved here [Java version number sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375067/java-version-number-sort)

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String[] arr = {"5.20", "1", "2", "5.2", "5.1", "3", "5.10"};
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
    list.sort(new VersionNumberComparator());
    for (String el : list)
        System.out.println(el);
}

public static class VersionNumberComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String version1, String version2) {
        String[] v1 = version1.split("\\.");
        String[] v2 = version2.split("\\.");
        int major1 = major(v1);
        int major2 = major(v2);
        if (major1 == major2) {
            return minor(v1).compareTo(minor(v2));
        }
        return major1 > major2 ? 1 : -1;
    }

    private int major(String[] version) {
        return Integer.parseInt(version[0]);
    }

    private Integer minor(String[] version) {
        return version.length > 1 ? Integer.parseInt(version[1]) : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: That will put `5.10` in front of `5.2`, which does not match the requirement.

Comment: You are totally right, there needs maybe a custom Comparator be written to accomplish the task.

Comment: This problem was maybe fixed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375067/java-version-number-sort